# Polynomials that are equal to values of prime numbers infinitely often

Tags: number-theory

I am not an expert in number theory and would 
like to know the answer to these questions 1 and 1a.

In both questions below the polynomial has integer
coefficients.

1) Does there exist a positive integer valued polynomial,
of degree 2 or greater,that is prime infinitely often?
This question means that the polynomial can take composite
values or values that are a prime numbers; and the number of distinct 
prime value it could take are infinite. This question seems fundamental, as it is a natural generalisation of Dirichlet's, but I could not find an answer to it.

1A) A similar question and a variation of the above question is-does there exist a positive integer valued polynomial,a polynomial in an exponential function (i.e. fixed positive base integer raised to the power of a given integer), that is prime infinitely often? - the Mersenne prime, or Mersenne type primes, would be a special case of this question.

If the answer is no to both the above then what are the known results that come closest to answering the questions?

Comment: Ad 1) This is an open problem, but it is conjectured to be so for some polynomials (e.g. such as $x^2+1$), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture. Ad 1A) Do you mean $f(a^n)$ is prime for infintely many $n$ and polynomial $f(x)$? If so, that would imply 1) and so it is open as well...

Comment: No expression of the type you are looking for is known to produce infinite many primes, but it is known that $a^2+b^4$ is prime for infinite many integer pairs $(a/b)$

Comment: Do you mean f(an) is prime for infintely many n and polynomial f(x)? Yes -question 1A is similar to 1.

Comment: The Bunyakovsky conjecture is believed true because it predicts not only that there are infinitely many primes in the values of $f(n)$ but also their density, and this density can be checked numerically and is found to hold pretty well for the numerous polynomials tested. The Bunyakovsky conjecture has been proven only for $ax+b,\gcd(a,b)=1$ (Dirichlet theorem in arithmetic progressions, the density is called PNT in arithmetic progressions)

Comment: Take $p | f(a)$, then $\forall k, p | f(a+kp)$, thus "$\forall n, f(n)$ is prime" implies that $\forall k, f(a+kp)=\pm f(a)$ ie. $f(x)^2-f(a)^2$ has infinitely many zeros so $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @reuns Also, I just found now,according to the following page it was proved by Goldbach -in 1752-that there is no polynomial with integers coefficients that is prime for all of its integer values https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html

Comment: For 1, also see [Green-Tao extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem#Extensions_and_generalizations).